# setfacl fails on files created by Apache

Tags: acl

I have a directory owned by my user `vagrant`. The webserver (and web application) run as `www-data`.

Both users need to create and modify directories and files in this directory, regardless of who created them. As `vagrant` I can modify files created by `www-data`, but I can't create new files in directories created by `www-data`.

I believe I am stuck because I cannot alter the mask applied to directories created by `www-data`.

```
vagrant@iadev:/var/www/web$ sudo rm -r core/cache
vagrant@iadev:/var/www/web$ mkdir core/cache

vagrant@iadev:/var/www/web$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX,u:vagrant:rwX core/cache
vagrant@iadev:/var/www/web$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX,u:vagrant:rwX core/cache

vagrant@iadev:/var/www/web$ getfacl core/cache
# file: core/cache
# owner: vagrant
# group: vagrant
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx
user:vagrant:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:user:vagrant:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

I browse the web app and populate the cache

```
vagrant@iadev:/var/www/web$ getfacl core/cache/locks/
# file: core/cache/locks/
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx               #effective:r-x
user:vagrant:rwx                #effective:r-x
group::rwx                      #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:user:vagrant:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

vagrant@iadev:/var/www/web$ vi core/cache/locks/test.txt
```

When user `vagrant` tries to save a file in `core/cache/locks` it fails. I understand `#effective:r-x` is the problem, but I cannot work out how to change it.

I have tried ~30 `setfacl` command variations (including `-n` and `m:rwX`): what do I not understand?

Comment: does your mounted fs supports acl? does acl even works foe this mountpoint where files stored?

Comment: Yes and yes - as user `vagrant` I can modify files created by `www-data`, but not create new files in directories created by `www-data`

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem. Go and check what ACL `core/cache/locks/test.txt` has:

```
getfacl core/cache/locks/test.txt
```

Probably the directory default ACL has not applied to just-created file (output could be something like):

```
# file: test.txt
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

Restarting Apache helped me. Reloading did not.

On the other hand, I had another Apache instance which did not need any restart. Go figure.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/263953)

Comment: edited my answer